# Не вызывается диалог через боковую шторку

Tags: android, dialogfragment, android-navigation-drawer

Имеется диалог, который не вызывается по `id` из навигейшна.

в `MainActivity`

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.recent_activity) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (id == R.id.rate_dialog) {
            rateApp = new RateAppFragmentDialog();
            rateApp.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "rate");

    }

    return true;
}
```

Справедливости ради отмечу, что вызов активити через `intent` выше происходит как нужно.

`id` перепроверял, правильный.

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что это за черная мистика?

Comment: проверьте под дебаггером, заходит ли вовнутрь `if()`

Comment: @metalurgus не заходит

Comment: Значит id Не совпадает, хотите верьте, хотите - нет

Comment: Покажите xml с самим меню, я думаю, что id не совпадает. После скриншота я еще больше уверен, что вы сравниваете не с тем ID

Comment: @metalurgus да, в меню `id` = rate_app, отметьте как ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вовнутрь условия не заходит, значит не совпадает ID:

```
if (id == R.id.rate_dialog)
```

Судя по скриншоту, `R.id.rate_dialog` находится в файле `rate_dialog.xml`, который по моим догадкам является не файлом разметки меню, а файлом разметки самого диалога